# Add & Change the same sliders on buttons click

Tags: jquery

I have two buttons on my page. Can anyone suggest me how to add jquery sliders on buttons click. Also I need to change, say slider1 to slider2 on second button click. I tried it with ajax, but it failed. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is hard to tell you without any code,

Second i don't know if ajax will help you to slide you images that you want, See slider is working with `setInterval()` function means your image will change after some interval of time for more details see the basic example here [setInterval](http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/setinterval-example/#.T8X3nbAjFK8)

for click event just do something like :

```
var startSlide = setInterval(function(){}, yourtime);
```

if you want to start on click then do:

```
$('#yourid').click(function(){
var startSlide = setInterval(function(){ //do your stuff }, yourtime);
});
```

if you want to stop this slider on any event then just do like `clearInterval(startSlide)` this will stop your slider.

hope this will help you